# Prisma insert relation one to many

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I read about prisma as an ORM provider and than decided to give it a try. My knowledge in database querying especially postrgres is not very experience at the moment, so I got into a situation where I need some help for a proper solution.

Let's assume the following `schema.prisma`:

```
model languages {
  language_id                    Int                              @id @default(autoincrement())
  language_code                  String                           @db.VarChar
  translations_categories        translations_categories[]
}

model categories {
  category_id             Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  category_name           String                    @db.VarChar
  translations_categories translations_categories[]
}

model translations_categories {
  translation_id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  language_id       Int
  category_id       Int
  translation_value String     @db.VarChar
  categories        categories @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [category_id])
  language          languages  @relation(fields: [language_id], references: [language_id])
}
```

So I try to solve the following update query with some api data:

1. Add a new category and insert it's `category_name`
2. Add the given translations for this category within `translations_categories` (within this step, the provided information contains the `language_code`, not the `language_id`!)

The request body contains the following fields:

```
{
  id: 2
  identifier: "TEST-1"
  translations: {
    de: "german", 
    en: "english", 
    fr: "france", 
    it: "italian"
  }
}
```

The following questions have arisen:

1. Is it possible to achieve this workflow by a single query?
2. When inserting the `translation`, I thought it would be possible by the provided `language_code` on it's own, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're trying to do here. Could you explain what is the update query exactly?

Comment: No problem, I'll give a more detailed explanation!

Comment: So the update query should do the following steps: 
- update or create a new category with identifier (not unique!)
- add the related translations as well (stored within a separate table)
- language for a translations referenced by fk from translation table

So my problem is: how can I create or update these translations and put the related language within a single translation if I do not have the unique id of a language, just the language_code. Combination of lanuage_id and category_id in combination would be unique for the given translation (if already existing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating the schema in the following manner:

```
model languages {
  language_id             Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  language_code           String                    @unique
  translations_categories translations_categories[]
}

model categories {
  category_id             Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  category_name           String
  translations_categories translations_categories[]
}

model translations_categories {
  translation_id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  language_id       Int
  category_id       Int
  translation_value String
  categories        categories @relation(fields: [category_id], references: [category_id])
  language          languages  @relation(fields: [language_id], references: [language_id])

  @@unique([language_id, category_id])
}
```

The reason for this is that `language_code` will always be unique for each language so having the `@unique` would make it much easier to create or update the category.

So you could create/update the category as follows:

```
let data = {
  id: 2,
  identifier: 'TEST-1',
  translations: {
    de: 'german',
    en: 'english',
    fr: 'france',
    it: 'italian',
  },
}

let translations = Object.entries(data.translations).map(([key, val]) => ({
  language: {
    connectOrCreate: {
      where: { language_code: key },
      create: { language_code: key },
    },
  },
  translation_value: val,
}))

await prisma.categories.upsert({
  where: { category_id: data.id },
  create: {
    category_name: data.identifier,
    translations_categories: { create: translations },
  },
  update: {
    category_name: data.identifier,
    translations_categories: { create: translations },
  },
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete cascade using Prisma? Something like prima.categories.delete({ where: { id: id }, include: { translations: true }})?

Comment: Currently cascade deletes are [not yet supported](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2328) for many-to-many relations yet. I would suggest adding a to the request so that we can check the priority.

As for a workaround, you would need to delete the relation data first and then the parent data.

Comment: Feels unfortunate, that multiple queries are required.